# What bodily complications will present themselves with humans designed to grow as fast as horses?

Tags: biology, humans

Long story short a kind of human has been created that grows to adulthood/matures in the same time span as horses do(4 years). Their intended purpose is as an easily inflatable and replaceable workforce, but their fast growth rate might prove to work against their purpose(I assume there would be at least a few problems that won't be obvious because, really, what changes to humans won't cause issues?).

**What bodily complications will present themselves with humans designed to grow as fast as horses?**

(edited to clarrify as asking for bodily issues only, we ignore social and ethical issues here at EvilCo)

Comment: Inflatable? Figuratively perhaps. If they're specially bred and or engineered, can other aspects be altered like bumping mean IQ so they can learn something a bit more useful than the average 4 year old? Does the question become - "what aspects would also need to be adjusted to create such a useful workforce?"

Comment: Wow +1 that could yield an interesting story line... the "inflatable workforce" aspect of it would also have consequences.. I've put an answer.

Comment: i had someone in my class that was being treated for Acromegaly. he was having problems with accurately controlling his body. for example his walk was crude and his writing was horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: *"What bodily complications will present themselves with humans designed to grow as fast as horses?"*

Citing the doctors,

### Acromegaly

Early symptoms include: swollen hands and feet – you may notice a change in your ring or shoe size tiredness and difficulty sleeping, and sometimes sleep apnoea gradual changes in your facial features, such as your brow, lower jaw and nose getting larger, or your teeth becoming more widely spaced numbness and weakness in your hands, caused by a compressed nerve (carpal tunnel syndrome)

From: https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/acromegaly/

**Cancer**

Cancers are also a risk, when cellular division is forced to be accelerated. Some kids, especially with vulnerable genetics i.r.t. cancer will not survive.

Read: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6502963/

**Mental health of youngsters (and parents)**

People are no labor-resource-products. You may try to optimize your *"labor yield"* but I wonder if the resulting society will be a viable place. Suppose the rulers on your planet arranged their priorities this way, I think a story worth reading would not only touch medical issues.. there are interesting psychological angles to consider. The absence of childhood will yield *hardened* young people, like in a war. They could become reckless, cruel. A violent revolution is one of the dangers of your scenario. When you would put the minimum age of your labor force to 4-5 years, you'd get a lot of very angry youngsters *and* parents !

Answer (score 4):

Some studies of the Turkana Boy suggested that his growth rate was similar to what you suggested. Others have suggested that it wasn't quite that fast. We can compare to chimp development.

The physical body really doesn't have a problem with growing that fast. We do run into situations where a joint parts might need to catch up with other parts of the joint. But those are temporary.

The main issues with fast growth are mental and social. Humans tend to sexually mature once we reach a certain weight. Can you imagine what life would be like if people grew to sexual maturity with the brains of a 4 year old? Life could wind up short and brutal. Many people have trouble learning new stuff during sexual maturing. The reason why we have a much slower growth rate (with spurts at 6-7 and in teen years) is to help us learn all the skills we need to have to survive and be part of society. If humans grew that fast, they would not be able to learn complex skills enough to be part of a work force. At best, they would be useful for unskilled fighting.

In short, if humans grew that fast, they would not develop complex societies and EvilCo would not exist.

Comment: Maybe with a "Cyteen" style semi-programmable education system, where learning isn't organic but more downloadable. You'd end up with a lot of identically-thinking workers who don't think outside the box. Not sure what savings this has over just building better robots, since the robots by then would be pretty sophisticated, and the humans wouldn't be much more innovative than machines. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyteen

Answer (score 3):

**Brain Development would possibly suffer the most**

The biggest issue with having humans go through extremely rapid development like that is that you are skipping over multiple stages of human development in both physical, social, and psychological development.

Though the person has the physical appearance of an adult, they are not one. Even ignoring the ethical implications of this, the physical and mental effects on the person themselves cannot possibly be good. They would effectively be a toddler in a full-grown human body. While they would have all the necessary hardware to be a functioning adult, they would have none of the experience or awareness to control or understand any of what they are doing.

It takes time to develop the correct neural pathways you have as an adult. This is not something that can be rushed. There's a reason why most psychologists organize human development into stages. There are certain milestones that need to be reached at every age for a human to be healthy and happy.

Even something as basic as walking needs to be learned through experience. Children tend to stumble before they truly understand most motor functions. If you speed up physical development, you'll be left with countless humans that don't even know how to lift a pen or pencil properly. If you want these people to be workers, you are going to be disappointed as they would barely be able to do anything more complicated than pressing a button.

Language development is another trait that needs to be learned. It takes a while before a child is able to converse properly, so what is the corporation going to do if its workers are left with brains almost incapable of understanding human speech? How many four-year-olds would be able to comprehend complicated instructions like how to turn on a machine? At best you might be able to get them to understand the barebone essentials. At worst they would be unable to string together basic words and unable to comprehend even simple instructions.

Rather than having droves of easily replaceable workers, the factory would find itself dealing with an army of mentally underdeveloped children who have the size and strength of adults.

Without a basic knowledge of controlling their bowel movements or general hygiene, none of them would know how to use the bathroom or brush their teeth.

Congratulations, your corporation now smells like a waste treatment plant and all of your "workers" now need someone else to change and bathe them all.

Without enough time to develop their language, motor, or social skills before they die, none of them would have created the neural pathways necessary to be proper adults.

As a result, most of them are barely able to do complicated tasks such as picking up a pencil or typing on a computer, they have little to no understanding of the language so they cannot take orders, and none of them have developed any meaningful social skills so they would feel no need to carry out such orders even if they understood them.

A variety of mental disorders could arise as well. Being a child with an adult brain would lead definitely lead to intense sensory overload, leaving the child extremely confused and anxious.

Evil Co. would unravel if it ever put this plan past the experimental stage. Unless they have some way around it or cut the plan off fast, they would lose a remarkable amount of money. Rather than creating a useful workforce, it would be turning its factories into daycare centers.

Answer (score 1):

**No problem.**

Bears are bigger than us and they are mature at 4 years old.  They are intelligent at 4 years old.  We have not got some special physiology that bears don't have.   If you can GMO magic your human babies to grow up fast you can magic their brains to mature fast too, if that works for your story.

It is an interesting question - why humans mature so slowly.  It is definitely not hardwired into the mammal body plan.  It is an interesting thing that other social mammals (elephants, orcas) also mature slowly.  Slow maturation of the young might facilitate cooperativity because it takes a village; raising a slow maturing youngster works best with many adults involved.  Cooperativity then yields other fitness benefits to the cooperative individuals.

Comment: An attempt to raise a chimpanzee in parallel with a human resulted in the chimp matching or exceeded human performance ... until it hit a wall.  This happened *before 9 months*, by which point the experiment was terminated.  https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/guy-simultaneously-raised-chimp-and-baby-exactly-same-way-see-what-would-happen-180952171/ - ie, at the point where humans aren't capable of *walking*, human babies are better at cognitive tasks that the smartest animals (chimps) of similar age.  And babies keep getting smarter.